# Sort or groupby dataframe in python using given string

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have given dataframe

```
    Id    Direction Load    Unit
1   CN05059815  LoadFWD 0,0 NaN
2   CN05059815  LoadBWD 0,0 NaN
4   ....
    ....
```

and the given list.

`list =['CN05059830','CN05059946','CN05060010','CN05060064' ...]`

I would like to sort or group the data by a given element of the list.

For example,
The new data will have exactly the same sort as the list. The first column would start with`CN05059815` which doesn't belong to the list, then the second `CN05059830` `CN05059946 ...` are both belong to the list. With remaining the other data

Comment: Please do not name variables after built-ins. For example, use `lst` instead of `list`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I just gave an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use [Categorical Data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/categorical.html#reordering). Here's a minimal example:

```
# sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']})

# required ordering
lst = ['D', 'E', 'A', 'B']

# convert to categorical
df['col'] = df['col'].astype('category')

# set order, adding values not in lst to the front
order = list(set(df['col']) - set(lst)) + lst

# attach ordering information to categorical series
df['col'] = df['col'].cat.reorder_categories(order)

# apply ordering
df = df.sort_values('col')

print(df)

  col
2   C
5   F
3   D
4   E
0   A
1   B
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but with large data, it would duplicate some rows.

Comment: @khalildz34, I disagree. *Have you tested this solution?*

Comment: yes I have. it prints duplicates of any element found in the list. Like we have already 2 in dataframe with and with the element in the list, it would be 4

Comment: @khalildz34, In that case, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50537595/edit) your question with a **[mcve]**.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach and example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
})
list_ = ['d', 'b', 'a']
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    col
0   a
1   b
2   c
3   d
4   e
```

Then in order to sort the df with the list and its ordering:

```
df.reindex(df.assign(dummy=df['col'])['dummy'].apply(lambda x: list_.index(x) if x in list_ else -1).sort_values().index)
```

Output:

```
   col
2   c
4   e
3   d
1   b
0   a
```

Comment: it prints out but still not in the order of the list

Comment: Have you tested the solution as is? What order do you see?